# Why can't I "check now" an item I created?

Tags: zabbix

With zabbix server 4.2.5 I try to make an item with these parameters:
[printscreen of my item parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX8fN.jpg)

I want to get a log from one of my zabbix-agents.

When I press the *Check now* button on an item tab I get an error message:

"Cannot send request: wrong item type."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Check now" option only on passive agents, it's not available on active agents.

Answer (score 0):

*The reason was I've set the wrong Hostname parameter in the /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf. The value should be the host name of a "host" in terms of Zabbix.*

upd: The error persists. But the item seems to work...